# Deleting empty lines after replacing with empty string

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
let data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
   <mn>1</mn>
   <mo>=</mo>
   <semantics>
      <mrow>
         <mn>2</mn>
      </mrow>
      <annotation encoding="text/plain">2</annotation>
   </semantics>
   <mspace linebreak="newline" />
   <mn>2</mn>
   <mo>=</mo>
   <semantics>
      <mrow>
         <mn>3</mn>
      </mrow>
      <annotation encoding="text/plain">3</annotation>
   </semantics>
</math>`

const regex = /<annotation\s*[^>]*>(.|\n)*?<\/annotation>/
while(regex.test(data)) {
  data = data.replace(regex, '')
}

console.log(data)
```

After replacing the annotation tags with empty string, I want to delete that empty line.

Comment: Never use `(.|\n)*?`. There is a native `[^]` construct to match any char in ES standard. Or workarounds like `[\s\S]` / `[\d\D]` / `[\w\W]`

Comment: Ok, how to delete those empty lines coming from replacing annotation tags with empty string?